# mongodb group on month part of date

Tags: mongodb

I have the data below.  I want to run a query to group my results by category and month and return a total.

The first desired output is a nested array of month names with aggregated totals for all 12 months by category.  Months that are not present in the data will still be returned but have 0 as the total.

```
{"category":"Auto","month":{"Jan":9.12,"Feb":9.12,"Mar":0,...}},
{"category":"Fees","month":{..."Apr":0,"May":4.56,"Jun":0,...}},
{"category":"Travel","month":{..."Oct":0,"Nov":4.56,"Dec":0}}
```

The second desired output is an array that doesn't have nested months...

```
{"category":"Auto","Jan":4.56,"Feb":4.56,"Mar":0,...},
{"category":"Fees",..."Apr":0,"May":4.56,"Jun":0,...},
{"category":"Travel",..."Oct":0,"Nov":0,"Dec":4.56,}
```

How can these results be queried with Mongodb?  Here is the sample input data:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("583f6e6d14c8042dd7c153f1"),
    "transid" : 1,
    "category": "Auto",
    "postdate" : ISODate("2016-01-28T05:00:00.000Z"),
    "total" : 4.56 }

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("583f6e6d14c8042dd7c153f2"),
    "transid" : 5,
    "category": "Auto",
    "postdate" : ISODate("2016-01-31T05:00:00.000Z"),
    "total" : 4.56 }

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("583f6e6d14c8042dd7c153f3"),
    "transid" : 3,
    "category": "Auto",
    "postdate" : ISODate("2016-02-28T05:00:00.000Z"),
    "total" : 4.56 }

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("583f6e6d14c8042dd7c153f4"),
    "transid" : 2,
    "category": "Auto",
    "postdate" : ISODate("2016-02-31T05:00:00.000Z"),
    "total" : 4.56 }

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("583f6e6d14c8042dd7c153f5"),
    "transid" : 6,
    "category": "Fees",
    "postdate" : ISODate("2016-05-16T05:00:00.000Z"),
    "total" : 4.56 }

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("583f6e6d14c8042dd7c153f6"),
    "transid" : 7,
    "category": "Travel",
    "postdate" : ISODate("2016-11-13T05:00:00.000Z"),
    "total" : 4.56 }
```

I'm new to mongodb and come from a sql background so I feel I've been thinking about all this in sql terms.

Below is what I've tried so far based on reading through the mongodb documentation and attempting to translate "sql think".  I'm essentially trying to filter to a specified year (in this case 2016).  I'm then grouping by category and date.  And in the last step I plan to use project and the $cond keyword to "subaggregate" on month by specifying the start and end dates of each month and then assign the month name as Jan, Feb, etc...  I have syntax errors and I don't know if this is the right or best approach.

```
db.transactions.aggregate(
    [
     { $match: { "postdate": {$gte: new Date("2016-01-01")}} },
     { $group: { _id: {"category":"$category","postdate":"$postdate"} , "total": { $sum: "$debit" } } },
     { $project: {"_id":0,"category":"$_id.category",
        "month":{$cond: { 
                            $and: 
                                [
                                  { $gte: ["$_id.postdate", new Date("2016-01-01")] }, 
                                  { $lt:  ["$_id.postdate", new Date("2016-02-01")] }, 
                                ] 
                            },"Jan":"$sum"}
                 //repeat for all other 11 months...
     }}
    ]
)
```

Comment: I've found a solution that gets me close to my desired output for the first scenario, but it needs some tweaking because I can't get the months to show up.  I am going to keep playing with it, but it may set someone on the right track.  I found this solution on another post here: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25843255/mongodb-aggregate-count-on-multiple-fields-simultaneously

Comment: Here is what I have so far:      `db.transactions.aggregate([
        { $match: { "postdate": {$gte: new Date("2016-01-01")}} },
        { "$group": {
            "_id": {
                "category": "$category",
                "month": {"$month": "$postdate"}
            },
            "total": { "$sum": "$total" } 
        }},
        { "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id.category",
            "month": { "$push": { "month": "$month", "total": "$total" } }
        }}
    ]) `

Answer (score 0):

If you want to group by month you can use month operator. eg:

```
db.transaction.aggregate([{$group:{_id:{ $month:"$postdate"}, "total":{$sum:1}}}])
```

I am not sure what project is doing for you.