# Multiple groups and project using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying display aggregated data by a time range in Mongoose. My Data is like:

```
{company: "1" createdTime:"2017-01-01"}
{company: "1" createdTime:"2017-01-01"}

{company: "1" createdTime:"2017-01-02"}
{company: "2" createdTime:"2017-01-02"}

{company: "2" createdTime:"2017-01-03"}
{company: "3" createdTime:"2017-01-03"}
{company: "3" createdTime:"2017-01-03"}
```

I have created a query like:

```
{
    "aggregate": [{
            "$project": {
                "frequency": {
                    "$dateToString": {
                        "format": "%Y-%m-%d",
                        "date": "$createdTime"
                    }
                }
            }
        }, {
            "$group": {
                "_id": {
                    "date": "$frequency"
                },
                "count": {
                    "$sum": 1
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

and returns:

```
[
    {
        "_id": {
            "date": "2017-01-01"
        },
        "count": 2
    },
    {
        "_id": {
            "date": "2017-01-02"
        },
        "count": 2
    },
    {
        "_id": {
            "date": "2017-01-03"
        },
        "count": 3
    }
]
```

Which gives me the count for the overall occurrences for that particular date, which is fine.

I'm wanting to further break that down to give me the sum of occurrences per company for that date which should look something like this:

```
[
    {
        "_id": {
            "date": "2017-01-01",
            "companies": [{
                "company": 1,
                "count": 2
            }]
        },
        "count": 2
    },
    {
        "_id": {
            "date": "2017-01-02",
            "companies": [{
                "company": 1,
                "count": 1
            },{
                "company": 2,
                "count": 1
            }]
        },
        "count": 2
    },
    {
        "_id": {
            "date": "2017-01-03",
            ,
            "companies": [{
                "company": 2,
                "count": 1
            },{
                "company": 3,
                "count": 2
            }]]
        },
        "count": 3
    }
]
```

I've tried all sort of combinations but always get errors when i put in a second group and i can't work out how to do it?

---

EDIT

I wasn't able to use examples from the comments or they didn't work for my use case however, combining this information i came up with this:

```
{
    "aggregate": [{
            "$group": {
                "_id": {
                    "company": "$company",
                    "date": {
                        "$dayOfMonth": "$createdTime"
                    },
                    "month": {
                        "$month": "$createdTime"
                    },
                    "year": {
                        "$year": "$createdTime"
                    }

                },
                "count": {
                    "$sum": 1
                }
            }
        }, {
            "$group": {
                "_id": "$_id.company",
                "events": {
                    "$push": {
                        "date": "$_id.date",
                        "month": "$_id.month",
                        "year": "$_id.year",
                        "count": "$count"
                    }
                },
                "totalEvents": {
                    "$sum": "$count"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

which renders some results like:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "1",
        "dateCount": [
            {
                "date": 3,
                "month": 12,
                "year": 2017,
                "count": 40
            },
            {
                "date": 10,
                "month": 12,
                "year": 2017,
                "count": 8
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Ideally the date would be yyyy-mm-dd but using the full date in the query would include the time also resulting in an entry for each time not date. I guess this will do for now, i can easily create a date from this albeit it's a little more cumbersome but it'll do until anything better comes along.

---

Edit 2

```
[{
        "_id": ObjectId("5a38a03b33ccd28fb87f6dc9"),
        "createdBy": ObjectId("5a2e203fa567425b2cb411fc"),
        "appId": ObjectId("5a2e203fa567425b2cb411fb"),
        "eventName": "event",
        "userName": "person",
        "userEmail": "company__29",
        "organisation": "company",
        "module": "module",
        "createdTime": ISODate("2017-12-02T17:07:25.000Z")
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

Query:

```
{
    "aggregate": [{
            "$project": {
                "frequency": {
                    "$dateToString": {
                        "format": "%U",
                        "date": "$createdTime"
                    }
                }
            }
        }, {
            "$group": {
                "_id": {
                    "frequency": "$frequency",
                    "organisation": "$organisation"
                },
                "count": {
                    "$sum": 1
                }
            }
        }, {
            "$group": {
                "_id": {
                    "date": "$_id.frequency"
                },
                "count": {
                    "$sum": 1
                },
                "companies": {
                    "$push": {
                        "organisation": "$organisation",
                        "count": "$count"
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    ]
}
```

Comment: can you post a few solutions you tried so we can work on fixing the bugs?

Comment: Use first group `{"$group": {"_id": {"date": "$frequency", company:"$company"},"count": {"$sum":1}}}` and second group `{"$group": {"_id": {"date": "$_id.date"},"count": {"$sum":1},"companies":{"$push":{"company":"$_id.company","count":"$count"}}}}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongodb aggregate (count) on multiple fields simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25843255/mongodb-aggregate-count-on-multiple-fields-simultaneously)

Comment: Thanks i've updated my answer and would be welcome to improvements.

Comment: Np.Not sure why you can't use the example provided in last comment. I believe this does exactly what you are looking for. Try adding the code after project stage.

Comment: It's close but it doesn't group the companies it produces: [
    {
        "_id": {
            "date": "2017-12-02"
        },
        "count": 1,
        "companies": [
            {
                "count": 106
            }
        ]
    }]

Comment: is the field `company` name correct ? Can I see  a sample document ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's correct yes. I've added 'Edit 2' to the question. You'll see the company is actually organisation and date is actually createdTime

Comment: Thank you for providing the sample document and updated query . You are not referencing the correct variable in second group. It should be  `"organisation": "$_id.organisation"`

Comment: I tried adding this for the _id and in the push but still no no avail.

Comment: Really that doesn't sound right.Just to confirm you added this change in the second group push operator only. Do you see any data if you remove the second group ?

Comment: 100% sure - i get: [
    {
        "_id": {
            "organisation": null
        },
        "count": 9,
        "companies": [
            {
                "count": 488
            },
            {
                "count": 5108
            },
            {
                "count": 658
            },